# Scaling image in Android

Tags: android, image

I tried to scale an high-resolution image to the desired size of my android and then set it as wallpaper, but as result I have a scaled image with 'annoying alternate rows' that make the picture NOT attractive.

```
int newWidth = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
int newHeight = wallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimumHeight();


Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Comment: By 'annoying alternate rows', are you talking about banding? Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about banding... sorry my poor english

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't have a solution for you, but I've noticed this as well. There's some strange way that Android is handling the rescaling. If you try just using `wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmapOrg);`, do you still see the banding?

Comment: I've tried with a png and now there is no banding. The problem remains with jpeg files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are scaling the bitmap correctly.

You could try downloading GIMP (free software) and scale your image to match the main 3 resolutions of android phones.  This may produce a better result.

Comment: by "correctly" I guess you mean "In the way Android supports". Pity there isn't a way to do a high-quality downsample though...